Optimised Javascript/TS code to find the total quantity for each base item, when more than 1 cart item can be pointing to the same base item
I need the most efficient way to calculate the total quantity for each base item by going through a list of cart items and sum up the quantities for all cart items having the same base item.
My CartItem looks something like:
export interface CartItem {
    id: string;
    baseItem: BaseItem;
    quantity: number;
    addOns: string[]
}

export interface BaseItem {
    name: string;
    id: string;
}

There can be multiple CartItems for the same BaseItem basis the different AddOns / Variations.
My current solution is to use a Map, and it does work, however I think there could be a faster more optimised way of doing this.
      const itemQuantites: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();
      cart.items.forEach(
        cartItem => {
          // Check for a match, else add it to the Map
          if (itemQuantites.has(cartItem.baseItem.id)) {
            const currentQuantity = itemQuantites.get(cartItem.baseItem.id) ?? 0;
            itemQuantites.set(cartItem.baseItem.id, currentQuantity + cartItem.quantity);
          }
          else {
            itemQuantites.set(cartItem.baseItem.id, cartItem.quantity);
          }
        }
      );


How long does your implementation take for a typical (or very large) "cart"?

Your solution already is optimal in terms of complexity.

Doing both ?? 0 and if (itemQuantites.has(cartItem.baseItem.id)) is superfluous. Use only one of the approaches to handle items that are still missing from the map.

@Bergi Thank you for your valuable feedback. Although, I was wondering if there is a way to do this using some combination of Array.map() and Array.reduce(). Also, the ?? 0 is because Typescript complains about adding something that is of type number | undefined

@Pointy I haven't tried it on a 'large' cart per say, I was worried about device performance, and how this code would perform on low-end mobile devices / 5+ years older generation devices.

@ArnawGundawar Do not use map if you don't want to build another array. reduce is rather pointless since you are mutating the Map anyway (not building it in a chaining/folding style, like a sum is built from +), but you could use it or for of instead of forEach - it doesn't really make a difference.

@ArnawGundawar Re ?? 0, you can just use .get(…)! in TypeScript if you know the key exists. Still my recommendation would be to just drop the if and else instead, just writing for (const { baseItem: { id } } of cart.items) itemQuantites.set(id, (itemQuantites.get(id) ?? 0) + cartItem.quantity);

Either way, I doubt there is a measurable difference in speed between these, but feel free to measure it yourself.

@Bergi Sounds good, let me try that out! I'll also refactor to use the ! operator. Thanks for all your help!
